# Extremely slow to find <select> element on Firefox 31 and Selenium 2.42.2

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I'm testing with firefox webdriver and it works quite well until firefox upgraded to 31 recently. It will take several minutes for the firefox webdriver to find a  element, which took less than a second in the older version.

This does not happen in all web pages, nor all  elements on the same page. It seems only the first one will take such long time.

Did anyone get into similar issue? Any advice will be deeply appreciated, thanks in advance!

regards,
Hanbo

Below are the selenum logs for reference:

```
  18:02:55.941 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03
  18:02:55.944 INFO - OS: Windows 8 6.2 amd64
  18:02:55.961 INFO - v2.42.2, with Core v2.42.2. Built from revision 6a6995d
  ......
  18:03:42.840 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAHWQ+UQAAAAAAAAAA..., browserName=firefox, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}]])
  18:03:42.865 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAHWQ+UQAAAAAAAAAA..., browserName=firefox, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}]
  18:03:50.423 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAHWQ+UQAAAAAAAAAA..., browserName=firefox, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}]]
  18:03:50.454 INFO - Executing: [set window position])
  18:03:50.483 INFO - Done: [set window position]
  18:03:50.491 INFO - Executing: [set window size])
  18:03:50.513 INFO - Done: [set window size]
  18:03:50.522 INFO - Executing: [page load wait: 60000])
  18:03:50.545 INFO - Done: [page load wait: 60000]
  18:03:50.552 INFO - Executing: [implicitly wait: 1000])
  18:03:50.565 INFO - Done: [implicitly wait: 1000]
  18:03:50.573 INFO - Executing: [set script timeoutt: 60000])
  18:03:50.589 INFO - Done: [set script timeoutt: 60000]
  18:03:50.596 INFO - Executing: [get: https://user:password@test.site])
  18:03:53.048 INFO - Done: [get:  https://user:password@test.site]
  ......here goes the first element, nearly 4 minutes and NO timeout
  18:04:09.796 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: input-dialog-year])
  18:07:44.731 INFO - Done: [find element: By.id: input-dialog-year]
  ......the second less than 1 second
  18:07:46.784 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: input-dialog-month])
  18:07:46.799 INFO - Done: [find element: By.id: input-dialog-month]
  ......all the follwing are normal
  18:07:48.960 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: info_sex_2])
  18:07:48.972 INFO - Done: [find element: By.id: info_sex_2]
```

Comment: Selenium doesn't support FF31. So I'd be surprised if it works at all.

Comment: @Arran, any idea when FF31 will be supported? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [changelog](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG)

- Update to support native events for Firefox 28 (removed native event
  support for Firefox 26). Native events are now supported for the
  following Firefox versions:

  - 17 (immediately previous ESR release)
  - 24 (current ESR release)
  - 27 (immediately previous release
  - 28 (current release)

So I think your best bet would be to roll back your firefox install to one of the versions listed above.  Mozilla keeps a repo of previous version [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/).